# How to write rspec test to check if post returned by index are owned by current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, functional-testing

I would like to write a test for my index method that takes into account the signed in user and checks if the index method only shows posts belonging to that user.

Notes_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "GET #index" do

it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
  get :index
  expect(response).to be_success
  expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
end

it "renders the index template" do
  get :index
  expect(response).to render_template("index")
end

it "returns only posts by user" do




end
```

notes_controller.rb

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /notes
  # GET /notes.json
  def index
        @users = User.order(:created_at)
    Rails.logger.info("#{current_user.id == @users[0].id}")
        if current_user.equal? @users[0] 
            @notes = Note.all
        else
      @notes = Note.where(user: current_user)
        end
    respond_to do |format|
    format.nil? { }
    format.html { }
    format.xml {
        @users = User.order(:created_at)
        if @users.first == current_user then
            render xml: @notes
        else
            return head(:unauthorized)
        end
    }
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Scheme of this:

1. You must create notes
2. Create user
3. Then authenticate user
4. Ater check count of user's notes count:

Approximately so:

```
@user = User.create
sign_in @user
10.times { Note.create(user: @user) }
10.times { Note.create }
get :index
assigns(:notes).should have(10).notes
```